# React Native Tabbar iOS binding issue [Expected a component class, got object Object]

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I've got a simple React Native app with a TabBarIOS component.
For each tab, I have a seperate .js file and the main TabBarIOS component lives in index.ios.js. The other classes are home.ios.js and contact.ios.js.

After I click on an icon I want the app to show the corresponding page( home.ios.js or contact.ios.js). However when I click one of the icons, I get a "Expected a component class, got object Object" error.

So far it looks like the rendering of the TabBarIOS component is alright. I myself think that there is a problem in the binding with the other .js files or a problem with the injection.

index.ios.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');

import Home from './home.ios';
import Contact from './contact.ios';

var {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS,
} = ReactNative;

var {
    Component
} = React;


class Tab extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedTab: 'Home'
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Home'}
                systemIcon="featured"
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedTab: 'Home',
                    });
                }}>
                <home/>
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Contact'}
                systemIcon="contacts"
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedTab: 'Contact',
                    });
                }}>
                <contact/>
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
        </TabBarIOS>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProtoReactNative', () => Tab);
```

home.ios.js (I include only this one, contact.ios.js looks the same)

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text
} = ReactNative;

var {
    Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
    }
});

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                    Welcome to your React Native Start Component!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Home;
```

Hopefully someone has a solution for me!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');

var {
    StyleSheet,
} = ReactNative;

var {
    View,
    Text,
    Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
});

class Contact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                    This could be your second tab
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Contact;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Change `<home/>` to `<Home/>` and `<contact/>` to `<Contact/>`

Step 2: Inside contact js file, **View** and **Text** should be imported from **ReactNative**. Currently its imported from **React**

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I get the following error: Element type is invalid: expected a string(for build in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'Contact'.

Comment: Issue is inside Contact js file then. Would be helpful if you post the code of that file

Comment: Awesome, this was the problem! Thanks